# PHP - Responding to incoming API call without returning

Tags: php, api, integration, webhooks

I'm trying to figure out the best way to send a response to an incoming API POST to our system, without returning.

We receive an XML post from another service, and consume it, and then our response to them is in XML also. What we are currently doing is digesting the incoming post, do some stuff on our end, then do a php return with the XML.

I would like to change this so that we can respond to their call with the XML, but then do some processing after the fact, without making some type of exec/background call.

What's the best way to send a response in PHP without returning? If we do an "echo" will that close the connection and allow us to process more afterwards without the other server "waiting?

Answer (score 3):

Calling PHP's `echo` will not close the connection, in fact you can call `echo` multiple times in your PHP script and the output will be added to the response. The connection will only close when

1. The end of the script is reached
2. `exit()` or the alias `die()` are called
3. A fatal/parse error or an uncaught Exception occurs or your server runs out of memory
4. The maximum script execution time which you can set in php.ini is exceeded

Usually, the calling client code will also have some kind of timeout, so if your 'digesting' code could take longer and you want to take care about this as well as point 4 in the list, you can store the request data for later processing, for example in a database or serialized in files. Having successfully stored the data, you then have basically 2 options to go:

**Option 1: Spawn a background PHP process**

To spawn a background PHP process that will survive the livecycle of the calling script, use `exec` and `nohup`. The basic usage could look like this:

```
exec('RESOURCE_ID=123 nohup /path/to/your/php/executable your_script.php > /dev/null');
```

Within the first segment of the command, `RESOURCE_ID=123`, you can pass a unique identifier of the previously stored request data, maybe a database entry id or the storage filename, to the background script. Use `getenv('RESOURCE_ID')` in your background script to retrieve the variable.

[EDIT] `> /dev/null` for output redirection is crucial for running the process in the background, otherwise the parent script will wait for the output of the background process. I also suggest to write the output as well as error output to an actual file like `&> my_script.out`, this will have the same effect. You could also get the process id of the background process by appending `& echo $!` to the command, `exec()` will then return it.

After starting the background script, you can send your 'OK' response and exit the parent script.

**Option 2: Cronjob for processing, as suggested by Jim Panse**

The more complex your system grows, you probably need more control over the execution of your 'digesting' code. Perhaps you want to balance server load peaks, or restart failed tasks, or throttle malicious usage of your API. If you need this kind of control, you are better off with this option.

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the case, but thank you for the information.

Comment: When you wire up a fixed process call in your code, you are usually not able to *not* run them. Means: starting your main process implicit ends in starting your background process. Since further process calls from another php processes are normally detached from every debugging of the main process, they are harder to control and therefore harder to debug. On the other side, a scheduler can be easily stopped and the php code ran manually.

Comment: @Jim Panse, I generally agree, and must admit that I don't know how it affects Xdebug for example, which I don't use. But I believe there is a use-case  for option 1. Waiting up to 1min for the next cronjob to run and for any previously queued tasks to finish could be inacceptable sometimes.

Comment: @Benni there are indeed valid use cases especially if you don't need to run a complex system. As everywhere in life, it's always a trade off and depends on the concrete situation. To solve the 1-min gap you could introduce some kind of worker process which is running for exactly one minute and looking for changes. As i said, you don't need this all if you have a simple situation. But if the system gets more complex you might consider more capable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since i guess you want your system-to-system communication synchronously there are multiple things you can consider.

Even though time consuming requests you usually still want a fast response. 
To satisfy this you can't process the request immediately.

So, just save the request and process it later (give the client a 202 response back). Systems like queues are very popular to save time consuming jobs for running them later. Another time controlled script (cronjob) could then do polling and process the stacked messages/data.

If you want to provide the results to the client too, return them a unique resource id on the initial rest call and implement another resource with exactly this parameter as the input. If your system finished processing, the result will appear there.

Spawning a process from within another php script isn't very handy since it's very difficult to debug and error-prone.

I personally would't go for this solution.